# How to do code autocompletion in swiftui?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I wanna create a VStack with spacing to 0 ,like this

[image]

But the only autocompletion tip is this:

[image]
And if i select this, the code generated will be like this:

[image]

I have to set parameters for alignment manually, which can be omit in first picture. Is there anyway to do auto-completion like the first picture?

Comment: Because the parameters are all optional, you do not need to include them. Just keep typing "spacing:" after the autocomplete prompt. You can in this case, and generally, delete any parameters that take an optional value.

Comment: This is not a SwiftUI question, rather it regards Xcode. Autocompletion proposes either the only required parameters or all the parameters. There's no "selective mode" autocomplete. In this case, all 3 parameters are optional, so they all appear together. Just delete what you don't need to set.

Answer (score -1):

You can just remove the alignment part from VStack and use VStack(spacing: 0) option.